# Why is my SQL Server reporting CLR_AUTO_EVENT waits when I don't even use SQL CLR?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-clr, wait-types

When I run this query, I see high wait time for `CLR_AUTO_EVENT`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    sys.dm_os_wait_stats
WHERE
    wait_type IN
    (
        'CLR_AUTO_EVENT',
        'CLR_CRST',
        'CLR_JOIN',
        'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT',
        'CLR_MEMORY_SPY',
        'CLR_MONITOR',
        'CLR_RWLOCK_READER',
        'CLR_RWLOCK_WRITER',
        'CLR_SEMAPHORE',
        'CLR_TASK_START',
        'CLRHOST_STATE_ACCESS',
        'ASSEMBLY_LOAD',
        'FS_GARBAGE_COLLECTOR_SHUTDOWN',
        'SQLCLR_APPDOMAIN',
        'SQLCLR_ASSEMBLY',
        'SQLCLR_DEADLOCK_DETECTION',
        'SQLCLR_QUANTUM_PUNISHMENT'
    )
ORDER BY
    wait_time_ms DESC,
    wait_type ASC;
```

[image: wait types]

In a related question [What is the SQLCLR wait type in Activity Monitor within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135849/what-is-the-sqlclr-wait-type-in-activity-monitor-within-sql-server-management-st)
, I read that it appears when running .NET managed code within SQL Server.

However, **I don't think I'm using any of that.** When I execute `EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'`, I see:

[image: clr enabled]

It looks to me like it's not even enabled. Can anybody please explain what's going on?

PS: I'm running SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition (14.0.3026.27).

Comment: Tom, please read paragraph 3 of that linked answer. I state that the "clr enabled" configuration option is only for "custom" assemblies, not anything system related. SQL Server uses CLR for several features, such as replication, change tracking, the 3 CLR datatypes (Geometry, Geography, HierarchyID), plus some of the newer built-in functions such as PARSE, TRY_PARSE, FORMAT, COMPRESS, etc.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky You're right, I can't believe I missed that, sorry. And thank you for the details about which features those are, it's good to know.

Comment: Tom, no problem. And just to be clear, that was not a complete list of where CLR is being used in SQL Server. There are definitely more places. I think SSIS is one of them, plus others. I will try to add more of them to the first article in my [Stairway to SQLCLR](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server uses CLR internally for several features, and these waits track CLR background threads just sitting around waiting on a ManualResetEvent or a AutoResetEvent.  According to [High waits on CLR_MANUAL_EVENT and CLR_AUTO_EVENT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/02/05/high-waits-on-clr_manual_event-and-clr_auto_event/) these are background waits (ie the wait time is not happening to user sessions), and can safely be ignored unless you have unsafe CLR code using these events directly.